# Windows Script Host cannot reference type library with version number in hexadecimal notation

Tags: .net, com, wsh, typelib, regasm

I have .NET framework assembly which is exposed to COM. Recently, since the assembly minor version number reach 10, it stopped being usable from Windows Script Host (WSH).

```cs
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.10.0.0")]
```

The `TypeLib` registry entry for some obscure reason uses hexadecimal notation, when storing the version number:
[BUG: The Regasm Tool Registers the Type Library with the Decimal Value Instead of the Hexadecimal Value](https://web.archive.org/web/20100204080931/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816970)

In this case it would be `1.a`:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{D766F0C8-9968-4A72-B918-D2780AEE7399}\1.a]
@="myassembly"
```

When the assembly is referenced in WSF file, WSH/`cscript` breaks whenever `a`–`f` "digits" are present in the version number. So it works for `1.0` or `1.9`, does not work for `1.10` (`1.a`) or `1.15` (`1.f`), but works again for `1.16` (`1.10`) or `1.25` (`1.19`), and does not work again for `1.26` (`1.1a`) (I didn't check all intermediate values, but the pattern seems to be clear).

```xml
<job>
<reference object="myassembly.Class1" />
<script language="JScript">
...
</script>
</job>
```

The `cscript` says:

> Windows Script Host: Cannot add reference : {D766F0C8-9968-4A72-B918-D2780AEE7399}

It seems like a bug in the WSH/`cscript` to me. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the WSH reference node to work it must be capable of loading a [COM Automation Type library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms221060(v=vs.85)) (TLB) from the `reference` node.

There are two ways for that:

1. the COM server embeds a TYPELIB Win32 resource
2. the CLSID registry key associated with the COM server indicates what is the TLB Id and its version

It works w/o effort with COM servers such as ADODB.Recordset because they are in case 1).

In the .NET case, the .NET .dll doesn't embed any TLB information so you must indicate it. So to fix it you must:

- Create a `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{yourclsid}\TypeLib` with a default value equal to your TYPELIB identifier formmated as {guid}
- Create a `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{yourclsid}\Version` with a default value equal to your version, ie: "1.10"

Why you don't need that when minor version is < 10 is probably a bug in scrobj.dll (which implements WSH parsing). I suspect the code 1) uses default *1.something* value when nothing is specified and 2) is broken when the major or minor versions are hexa. Here is a dump of the function that does it, it uses [strtoul](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/) with a 10 radix/base instead of 16:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though note that it's not that it works for versions that have the same decimal and hexadecimal representation (`1.0` through `1.9`). It seems to work for any version whose hexadecimal representation do not contain any `a`–`f` digits (as my question says). So it works for `1.0` or `1.9`, does not work for `1.10` or `1.15`, but works again for `1.16` or `1.25`, and does not work again for `1.26` (I didn't check all intermediate values, but the pattern seems to be clear).

Comment: Yes, it's really bugged :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @Simon wrote in his answer, the problem can be *worked around* by creating `Version` key.

This updated .NET C# registration code does it:

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: Guid("D766F0C8-9968-4A72-B918-D2780AEE7399")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.20.0.0")]

namespace netregasm
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
    [Guid("F6FAF39E-8E51-443B-9170-72D63A6E9A6B")]
    public sealed class TheClass
    {
        public TheClass()
        {
        }

        public int Test()
        {
            return 5;
        }

        [ComRegisterFunction]
        private static void ComRegister(Type t)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(t);

            string guid = Marshal.GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly(assembly).ToString();

            int major, minor;
            Marshal.GetTypeLibVersionForAssembly(assembly, out major, out minor);
            string version = $"{major}.{minor}";

            RegistryKey root = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            root.CreateSubKey(GetTypeLibKey(t)).SetValue(null, guid);
            root.CreateSubKey(GetVersionKey(t)).SetValue(null, version);
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        private static void ComUnregister(Type t)
        {
            RegistryKey root = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            root.DeleteSubKey(GetTypeLibKey(t), false);
            root.DeleteSubKey(GetVersionKey(t), false);
        }

        private static string GetClsidKey(Type t)
        {
            return "CLSID\\" + t.GUID.ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant();
        }

        private static string GetTypeLibKey(Type t)
        {
            return GetClsidKey(t) + "\\TypeLib";
        }

        private static string GetVersionKey(Type t)
        {
            return GetClsidKey(t) + "\\Version";
        }
    }
}
```